# Is storing data greater than 8kB in a SQL Server row bad practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and my question is as follows: I have a table of a few columns. For one column I specified `nvarchar(MAX)` as its datatype, but the recommended specifications are for max 8KB of row capacity.

The `nvarchar(MAX)` column in my case is supposed to have at most 30kB. Will the row indexing cause trouble for IO operations? Should I instead use a fragmentation structure of each 6kB.

Table_Content1

```
| Index(tinyint)  | [Data](nvarchar(6096))    |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
|     1           | Blablablabla....          |
|     2           | Blalalalall....           |
|     3           | Blaa.                     |
```

But this approach will result in more tables to be created. Also I have to perform additional logic when User edits the content.

Currently I am using SQL Server. Also looking forward to other platforms.

Comment: which database engine are you using? Oracle, Mysql, Posgtres, other?

Comment: Using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is "no" -- not bad ***practice*** to store more than 8kB in a row (i.e., most of the time you don't have much of a choice); a table in the real world will often consist of many columns because of application design and business requirements--it's almost impossible to keep a row to less than 8kB in many cases.

The 8kB standard is a legacy spec due to HDD disk blocks being generally 8kB -- read a disk block into memory and move on from there.  Often times, there are columns that need to support a size greater than 8kb (like a large text field, JSON field, or even a bytearray field) -- at least for Postgres, there's `TOAST` (The Oversized-Attribute Storage Technique), which is built-in (no extensions required) to handle such large fields.

That said, `SELECT`ing a row that's bigger than 8kB might be slower than `SELECT`ing a rows that's smaller than 8kB, so if you're concerned about performance, you may need to evaluate your data design/architecture, indexing practices, and hardware arrangement.  Then again, it might not be a good idea to fragment your data just for the sake of keeping your rows small--technical debt comes in many forms.

Comment: Whats the performance at 100k rows with an estimated 1Kb-30Kb, average 3Kb general row size?

Comment: Are you asking about Postgres?  It depends on what you've got in the table, really.  I don't know anything about SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Do not fragment the data unnecessarily.  The issue with the 8k row size is because you cannot define a row with that length *unless* you use variable sized columns such as `varchar(max)`.

If your data requires such a column, then use it.  Do note that it will be too long for traditional indexes.

Comment: Does SQL automatically retrieve the column value when larger than 8kB or does one need additional coding?

Comment: @user123581321 . . . It fetches the full values when you  return the column.  You don't need to understand the underlying storage mechanisms to use databases.